# ios APNS token is Invalid with P8 Key

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm using .p8 key to send notifications from server , its working when the app is installed from Xcode but when Using Ad-hoc ipa its not working and I got Invalid token Message , I know Ad-hoc uses Production Certificate , but .p8 key is just one I guess I doesn't have production and development , so whats the problem ?

Comment: Check your entitlements. Also make sure your server is not using Sandbox for Production.

Comment: @Brandon  APS Environment is Development , is this the problem ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292363/aps-environment-is-always-development

Comment: @Brandon I checked the link and got the problem but how to make sure my server is not using Sandbox for Production I'm just using this library to send notification from java server https://github.com/relayrides/pushy

Comment: @Brandon and another problem is that p8 doesn't have production version its just one , how to use p8 for production ? i'm not using old p12

Comment: `final Future<Void> connectFuture = apnsClient.connect(ApnsClient.DEVELOPMENT_APNS_HOST);`  Change `DEVELOPMENT_APNS_HOST` to the Production one..

Comment: @Brandon oh thanks so much I didn't see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using APNS Token based trust, Same P8 Key shall suffice for both development as well as production environment.

You just need to make sure your connected to respective development/production APNS host from your provider & also you need to use correct 'apns-topic' to identify your AppID & production 'device-token' to identify the end device for production environment.